# Copy data from last column and move into new column in a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, cut

I want to move the data in the last column into a new column with a particular column name in the file if possible.
The last column from which we move should be empty.

**Input:Sample file**

```
Col1,col2,col3,col4
1,abc,test,"Codes:1,2,3,4"
2,xyz,test1,"Codes:12,22,3,4"
3,def,test2,"Codes:1,22,3,41"
```

**Output:**

```
Col1,col2,col3,col4,codes
1,abc,test,,"1,2,3,4"
2,xyz,test1,,"12,22,3,4"
3,def,test2,,"1,22,3,41"
```

I was able to cut the data,but unable to move it into a new column

```
cut -d',' -f12- < file.csv | awk -F":" '{print $2}' | awk -F"\"" '{print $1}'
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach too.

Comment: Try `sed '1{s/$/,codes/;b};s/"Codes:/,"/' file`.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed :

```
sed '1s/$/,codes/;s/"Codes:/,"/' <file>
```

Using awk :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==1{print $0, "codes"}NR!=1{gsub("Codes:",""); $4 = FS $4; print}' <file>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print $0",codes"; next} {sub(/"[^:]+:/,",\"")} 1' file
Col1,col2,col3,col4,codes
1,abc,test,,"1,2,3,4"
2,xyz,test1,,"12,22,3,4"
3,def,test2,,"1,22,3,41"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1s/$/,codes/;1!s/"Codes:/,"/' file
```

For the first lines append `,codes`, all other lines replace `"Codes:` by `,"`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{sub(/\,\"[a-zA-Z]+:/,",,\"")} 1'  Input_file
```